# SAS Collating/summarizing observations over a time interval

Tags: sas, intervals, collate

I have a set of trading data that has observations in milliseconds but infrequent. To make it a reasonable timeseries I created a macro to build a grid (one observation per second). Now I want my dataset to fit into the grid (summing up the volumes that happened in that second and using the last quote/trade price. 
I am very thankful for any ideas. See code below.

Best

```
%macro makeGrid;
    proc sort data=data.inputdataset; by id date milliseconds descending type order; run;    
    options nomprint;
    data data.outputgrid (keep=id date miliseconds type order); 
    set data.inputdataset; 
    by id date; 
        if first.date;
        Type="grid"; Order=0;
        %do i=((9*60*60)+(10*60)) %to ((16*60*60)+(50*60)); 
            milliseconds=&i; output; 
        %end;
    run;
    options mprint;
%mend makeGrid;
```

A very desperate try was this:

```
data data.merged;
merge data.outputgrid data.inputdataset;
by id date milliseconds;
if first.id then do;
if milliseconds collate = sum(volume)
run;
```

Grid:

```
ID date time price volume
ABC 01/01/15 0801000 
ABC 01/01/15 0802000 
ABC 01/01/15 0803000 
ABC 01/01/15 0804000
```

Data example:

```
ID date time price volume
ABC 01/01/15 0800004 1,55 100
ABC 01/01/15 0800110 1,56 200
ABC 01/01/15 0800152 1,52 300
ABC 01/01/15 0800210 1,51 400
ABC 01/01/15 0800352 1,50 200
ABC 01/01/15 0800384 1,51 400
```

Output:

```
ID date time price volume
ABC 01/01/15 0801000 1,55 100
ABC 01/01/15 0802000 1,52 500
ABC 01/01/15 0803000 1,51 400
ABC 01/01/15 0804000 1,51 600
```

If there is no trade in that second, volume should be 0 and price the last second's price.

EDIT:

so, thanks to Chris I made the Grid without Macro, but the proc SQL is not working as I want.

```
data grid1;
do seconds = '09:10't to '16:50't ;
    output ;
  end ;
/*  id=.;*/
/*  date=.;*/
/*  format ric $12. ;*/
/*  format Date best12. ;*/
run;

 proc sql ;
  create table want as
  select a.id, a.date, a.miliseconds, sum(a.volume) as Volume
  from have a
     left join
       grid1 b  on a.id = b.id
                    and a.date = b.date
                    and a.miliseconds = floor(b.seconds)
  group by a.id, a.date, a.miliseconds ;
quit;
run;
```

So, id and date couldn't be found, so I created them in the data step. But then id isn't the same format, which I tried to fix but failed. 
It seems I have an error when merging the have dataset to the want by matching the miliseconds between the seconds gridlines.
What am I missing? Always thankful for input! 
Best

Comment: please provide a reproducible example of what you have and what you want to be the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you all for the answers.
I figured how to do it. There might be an easier way but for me, this now is sufficient:

```
data data.test;
set data.taq;
next_full_sec = int((miliseconds-1) / 1000) + 1;
run;

data data.grid;
do seconds = 1 to 86400;
  output;
end;
run;

proc summary data=data.test;
by ric date time next_full_sec;
var volume;
output out=data.int (drop=_type_) sum=;
run;

proc sort data=data.test (keep=ric date) out=data.id_date nodupkey;
by ric date time;
run;

proc sql;
create table data.testseconds as
select ric, date, time, seconds
from data.id_date, data.grid
order by ric, date, time, seconds
;
quit;

data data.testout;
merge
  data.testseconds (in=a rename=(fullseconds=next_full_sec))
  data.int (in=b)
;
by ric date time next_full_sec;
if a;
if not b
then do;
  _freq_ = 0;
  volume = 0;
end;
run;

proc print noobs;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, why a macro to create your one-second intervals?

```
  do time = '09:10't to '16:50't ;
    output ;
  end ;
```

Assuming your `milliseconds` is just a time to 3 decimal places, simply join `floor(time)` to the intervals accordingly, then summarize.

```
proc sql ;
  create table want as
  select a.id, a.date, a.time, sum(b.volume) as Volume
  from grid a
       left join
       inputdataset b on a.id   = b.id
                     and a.date = b.date
                     and a.time = floor(b.time)
  group by a.id, a.date, a.time ;
quit ;
```

You can then post-process this dataset, to set missing Volumes to zero or retaining the previous price accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am trying it. I need milliseconds from midnight to continue my calculations. But is a merge possible, that collates the volumes onto the grid? Proc SQL is already helpful.

Comment: Just change the `do` loop to `do time = '00:00't to '23:59't`.

Comment: Okay the Grid is working, but as edited in the question: I cannot merge it as a.id = b.id is another format. But formating it doesn't help...

Comment: Do a `proc contents` of each of your tables to ascertain why the `ID` fields are different, and convert one to match the other.